# Issue running chrome driver in docker image

Tags: macos, docker, selenium, dockerfile

I have written some scripts to extract some data from website using selenium. Although my code runs well outside of docker container, it fails when I run it after building an image. I searched through the google and looked over the internet to find the similar issue but could not find something similar. Here I have posted my docker file,

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

FROM python:latest

WORKDIR /Users/ufomammut/Documents/eplrestapi
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
RUN curl https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/90.0.4430.24/chromedriver_linux64.zip -O
RUN unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip 

COPY . .


CMD [ "python3", "epl.py"]
```

The error message I receive when I run the docker image that I built,

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ufomammut/Documents/eplrestapi/epl.py", line 172, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Chrome("./chromedriver",options = chr_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 98, in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 109, in assert_process_still_running
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service ./chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 255
```

In my code I have provided the path to the chromedriver as follows:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome("./chromedriver",options = chr_options)
```

Right now I used linux arm64 python base image and was able to curl and unzip the chromedriver as reflected in my dockerfile above.I am no longer receiving the format error but I am receiving this error message as I posted above where it says the chromedriver unexpectedly exited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to have copied a `chromedriver` binary built for MacOS into a Debian machine.
Based on how you've tagged this question with `macos` and the image `python:3.9.5-slim-buster` you are using is `amd64` based on Debian.

I suggest you continue persisting with trying to `curl` the Linux 64 bit [chromedriver](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/90.0.4430.24/chromedriver_linux64.zip) into your machine via your `Dockerfile`.

To test it in your host OS you can simply change your current `chromedriver` binary to `chromedriver.bakup`.  Download the `linux` version to `chromedriver` and rebuild your docker machine and it will copy the linux version into the new image.

Comment: @Igflorentino I am not sure why I need to have chromedriver built for linux machine instead of mac. I think I don't know something about docker. Through the dockerhub I was not able to find any python images built for macos arm64 machine.

Comment: @Ufomammut With virtualisation tech like `docker` you are running 2 different computer architectures. The host OS which in your case is **OSX** and the target OS which in your case is **Debian** `x86_64` inside your docker machine. You simply need to find the correct binary to run inside your target OS. This doesn't apply to all files but for binaries you will need to either build for your target OS or download one that is prebuilt for the target. I did a small test to get `chromedriver` working here [Gist](https://gist.github.com/lgflorentino/46f2a6446c08c0174dda5eb65786781b).

Comment: I ran the test inside a `python:3.9.5-slim-buster` container using the `docker` `exec` command.

Comment: @Igflorentino Right now I ran into a different problem. I am noticing that with some python images, I don't have to install curl. But with python slim buster 3.9.5, I have to install curl and download the linux chrome driver. But right now the error message that I am getting is what I have updated in the question.

Service ./chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 255
Not sure where I am having the issue right now. But I will am trying to google right now. Let me know if you know what's going on.

Comment: The python images are described on the [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/python) page. If you scroll down to the **Image Variants** `python:<version>-slim` heading it says it's a very cut down version so they don't install `curl` by default. I don't know about the 255 error code but that seems like a different question. gl :)

Comment: @Igflorentino I downloaded the chromedriver from dockerfile but if I do not have separate chrome driver on my machine, the code does not seem to work at all.

Comment: @igflorentino After the fix you suggested which worked well where I was able to use curl and linux arm64 based chrome driver, right now I am receiving this error message,
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service ./chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 255

Comment: I suggest you shell into the docker container using `docker exec -it <container_name> /bin/bash` and run the `chromedriver` manually to see what the problem is. You can enable logging to get a better idea what the problem is. [Logging](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/logging).

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have been using `chromedriver` binary for MacOS instead of its linux version.

To make it a 'workable' piece of code, you can try linux binary and perform volume mapping when you try to run your docker image. Use the linux binary for `chromedriver` and put it in a seperate directory in your system which needs to be mapped. And when you run your image try using:

`docker run -v <directory_path_to_chromedriver>:<docker_image_directory_path> <image>`

Your final piece of code will be updated with your new binary file path.

`browser = webdriver.Chrome("<docker_image_directory_path>/chromedriver",options = chr_options)`

But for **permanent fix**, curl and unzip the linux binary while you build the docker image.

Comment: I am not sure why we should use chrome driver binary for linux as my machine is mac. I am using chrome driver for mac arm64. I am not sure how exactly does this thing works. In the docker hub also, I was not able to find images for mac.

Answer (score 1):

After going through the comments, I believe you're a little confused with Docker containers and how they interact with your system.

A Docker container runs it's own independent, isolated and optimised version of an operating system determined by the **FROM** layer, and leverages your system's kernel.

Now, you must use Chrome Webdriver binaries compatible with **linux arm64**, rightly pointed out by @Shubham and @lgflorentino. It seems that you've already done so.

Your next steps should be to check permissions on the Chrome Webdriver executables, and make sure that your container has setup all the environment paths and variables correctly.

You can do so by entering your container with the command **docker exec -it  /bin/bash** or **/bin/sh** and then manually execute your bins. This will give you a clearer picture.

Check your environment variables as well!
Also, an improved Dockerfile with reduced number of layers can be as well.

```
FROM python:latest
#Use a deterministic Python image, mention a version instead of 'latest'
WORKDIR /Users/ufomammut/Documents/eplrestapi
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt && \
    curl https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/90.0.4430.24/chromedriver_linux64.zip -O && \
    unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip 

COPY . .
#Try adding an ENV layer to make sure your paths are setup properly. (After debugging your container)
CMD [ "python3", "epl.py"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have tagged with macOs and ARM64, I believe that your development machine has Apple Silicon or M1 chip. The docker engine on the Apple Silicon machine will by default pulls ARM64 based images and your chrome driver is of linux64. This means your chrome driver can't run inside the host.

You can either use arm64 chrome driver or build docker image form amd64 platform.

```
docker build -t your-username/multiarch-example:manifest-amd64 --build-arg ARCH=amd64
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `--platform=linux/amd64` to the `FROM` statement.  I used this for Debian:

`FROM --platform=linux/amd64  python:3.9`